# Symbol directly after theorem number

Tags: mathematical-writing

I think it is generally agreed that one should not start a mathematical sentence with a symbol.  But what about this:

**Theorem 7.1.** $X$ is pseudoquasifinite.

I would say that this is acceptable, as "Theorem 7.1" is effectively the beginning of the sentence.  However, a referee has complained to me about this.  What do other people think?

Comment: Does not really matter, what you, the referee or we think about that. The journal will just change it according to their standards, if necessary.

Comment: **Theorem 7.1.X:** is a pseudoquasifinite.

Comment: If I were the referee I would not have objected; that said, I don't think Theorem 7.1 is the start of the sentence. But I am not a grammarian or scholar of linguistics. Personally, I think the injunction against starting a sentence with a mathematical symbol is overstated, rather like the rule "do not start a sentence with 'but' "

Comment: Theorem 7.1. The widget $X$ is pseudoquasifinite.  Replace "widget" with whatever kind of object $X$ really is (a space, a module, etc.)